# Grails 3.1.4 Project with Swagger Documentation

Tags: grails, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

## Description

I am working with **Grails 3.1.4** and I am having problems documenting my Controller classes with the **Swagger Api**.

`grails -version` gives me this output:

```
| Grails Version: 3.1.4
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_73
```

I tried to integrate Swagger into the project using these sources:
 - https://grails.org/plugin/swaggydoc 
 - https://rahulsom.github.io/swaggydoc/

### According to these sources I have to do the following things:

#### 1. Add dependencies to `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.7'
compile 'io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:1.5.7'
compile "com.github.rahulsom:swaggydoc-commons:0.24.0"
compile "org.grails.plugins:swaggydoc:0.27.0"
```

#### 2. Add another repository to `build.gradle`:

```
`jcenter()`
```

#### 3. Annotate my Controller in the following fashion:

```
@Api(value = "myValue", description = "this controller does something")
@Path("/myapproot/myDomainClassX")
MyDomainClassXController{
    @GET
    @Path("/myFunction")
    def myFunction(){
        render "MyDomainClassXController, myFunction(), did something"
    }
}
```

#### 4. In the file `application.yml` I added:

```
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents: []
```

#### 5. The aforementioned sources write about a `Config.groovy` which I do not have, so instead of writing:

```
swaggydoc {
    contact = "developer@coer.com"
    description = "API description"
    title = "My Swagger Doc for my awesome project"
    apiVersion = "0.2cents"
}
```

#### 6. into the non-existent `Config.groovy`, I added the same text into the file `application.yml` using the yml syntax:

```
swaggydoc:
    contact: "developer@coder.com"
    description: "API Description"
    title: "My Swagger Doc for my awesome project"
    apiVersion: "0.2cents"
```

## Result

#### What works is:

I am running my Grails application with the `bootRun` task and browse to `http://localhost:8080/myapproot/myDomainClassX/myFunction` and see the String "MyDomainClassXController, myFunction(), did something" in my browser.

#### What not works is:

When I browse to `http://localhost:8080/myapproot/api` I get the **"Page Not Found (404)" Error**. Here i expected to see the magic of the Swagger annotations producing a documentation.

## Question

What did I do wrong in the configuration of the Swagger plugin mentioned in the sources?

Comment: Have you looked at [springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-grails-integration)? If not would love to get your feedback on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 404 on /myapproot/api check your UrlMappings.groovy file.

Either leave this default mapping in there:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

or at least allow

```
get "/api/$action?"(controller: 'api')
```

That should let you at least hit the swaggy controller with that URL.